# Is reproducible benchmarking possible?

Tags: node.js, microbenchmark, reproducible-research

I need to test some node frameworks, or at least their routing part. That means from the request arrives at the node process for processing until a route has been decided and a function/class with the business logic is called, e.g. just before calling it. I have looked hard and long for a suitable approach, but concluded that it must be done directly in the code and not using an external benchmark tool. I fear measuring the wrong attributes. I tried artillery and ab but they measure a lot more attributes then I want to measure, like RTT, bad OS scheduling, random tasks executing in the OS and so on. My initial benchmarks for my custom routing code using process.hrtime() shows approx. 0.220 ms (220 microseconds) execution time but the external measure shows 0.700 (700 microseconds) which is not an acceptable difference, since it's 3.18x additional time. Sometimes execution time jumps to 1.x seconds due to GC or system tasks. Now I wonder how a reproducible approach would look like? Maybe like this:

- Use Docker with Scientific Linux to get a somewhat controlled environment.
- A minimal docker container install, node enabled container only, no extras.
- Store time results in global scope until test is done and then save to disk.
- Terminate all applications with high/moderate diskIO and/or CPU on host OS.
- Measure time as explained before and crossing my fingers.

Any other recommendations to take into consideration?

Comment: GC should not be happening in the middle of running other JS except in dire memory emergencies (which you should not be hitting on a simple routing comparison).  GC should be happening when there is nothing else to do.

Comment: In a perfect world that is the intention of GC's yes. However, I don't know any GC that actually is positive to use and I tried many programming languages and solutions. GC is generally bad, I prefer to code better and disable GC totally. This system is intended to be under really heavy load for long periods of time.

Comment: Well, if you're trying to isolate a test on just one component without any effects of GC, then you should design the test such that GC won't be triggered during your test.  Run a short burst of activity that you're testing, then allow the system to breathe and catch up on any GC outside of an timings.  Then, repeat your test and breathe however many times you think you need to.  It's a matter of designing your test to test just what you want to measure and isolate the other things.

Comment: In the real world of Javascript, a system that is heavily loaded for awhile will have to face GC.  That's the system you've chosen with node.js.  If you don't want GC, then go write your program in C or C++.  Don't pick a GCed environment, then complain about having to deal with GC.  If you're trying to do a particular test without seeing the influences of GC, then design your test environment so you can test a short burst of activity and then allow GC to recover outside of the timed activity.

Comment: Good idea, I could run it for 10 second intervals, save the measure points for calculating an average for each candidate. I am trying to find a way to control the GC myself, since it is needed for production. Yes, I know the pros and cons of each technology, but people in charge did select the current technologies. I wanted something more predictive like C or similar.